# Doing an SVN merge on a different OS from most users - does this cause issues?

Tags: svn, merge, carriage-return

I am working in a place that develops software on Windows. We use SVN for version control. I work much more quickly in a bash shell, and was asked to do a merge of a tag into a branch. I automatically did it in a Linux VM as that's where I'm most at ease.

I have since done a diff of the merge and have seen a lot more changes than I expected. Is this a result of the differences between Windows and Unix (carriage-returns etc)?

Is there a way to avoid it or is it safer to just bite the bullet and do everything in Windows? I won't actually be developing any code inside this VM, I will only use it for merges and diffs.

Answer (score 0):

The diff itself should show what the changes are. I recommend getting a decent [diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792910/best-graphical-source-code-diff-viewer-editor-for-code-comparison-and-merging) and see for yourself. Since you mention line endings: You can read more about line endings in SVN [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857991/svn-line-ending-style).

Comment: Some text editors like Vim would show line endings, IIRC. Text files from Windows show up with things like `^M` on Vim. A diff tool should still be able to do that work, too.